# OOP INSERT INTO statement not working

Tags: php, sql, oop, sql-insert

I am creating a very simple message board to learn OOP-styled programming. The purpose is to display posts that are saved in the database, and beneath the displayed posts, you can add a new post to the database which will also display on the page.

I am having trouble with calling the function on the index.php page, so when I click on submit it will add the content in the textarea to the database. Any suggestions?

**Index.php**

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("prikbord.class.php");

$p = new Prikbord();
$bericht = $p->getbericht();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $p->setbericht($_POST[$bericht]);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Prikbord</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php 
            echo $p->showdata();
        ?>

        <form action="" type="post">
            <textarea name="bericht" placeholder="Uw bericht" style="display: block; width: 350px; height: 150px;"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Prikbord.class.php**

```
<?php

class Prikbord {

    private $db;
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "prikbord");

        if($this->db->connect_error) {
            die("Fout met database verbinding.");
        }
    }

    public function getbericht() {
        $sql = "SELECT naam, datum, bericht FROM prikbord";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->data[] = $row;
        }

        return $this->data;
    }

    public function showdata() {
        $return = "";

        foreach($this->data as $item) {
            $return .= "<div>" . $item["naam"] . "</div>";
            $return .= "<div>" . $item["datum"] . "</div>";
            $return .= "<div>" . $item["bericht"] . "</div>";
            $return .= "<hr style='width: 100px; float: left; display: inline;'>";
            $return .= "<br><br>";
        }

        return $return;
    }

    public function setbericht($bericht) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO prikbord(bericht) VALUES ('" . $bericht . "')";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($this->result) {
            echo "Data insert succesfully.";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What trouble are you having? Error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not posting your data at all. You should open your form like this:

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST">
```

**Note:** It's `method`, not `type`.

Comment: Didn't get anything back. Only thing was that the URL changed to: http://localhost:8888/ROC%20Tilburg/Webtechnieken/OOP/Opdracht%202/prikbord/?bericht=Test+message.&submit=submit. It didn't add the content of the textarea to the database.

Comment: The problem is you're not posting your form, see my updated answer.

Comment: That was a noob move. Thank you very much for your time.